# Standardized Euclidean Distance over variables distributed as $\chi^2$

Tags: multivariate-analysis, outliers, anomaly-detection

I sample $n$ dimension vectors (each sample is a vector). My objective is the detection of outliers. In case those elements would distribute normally, for outlier detection, I could use Standardized Euclidean Distance, followed by extraction of the survival function based on the $\chi^2_{n}$ distribution. Unfortunately, the elements in my vector distribute with respect to $\chi^2$. What tool I should use?

Remark: Before posting this question, I have looked into a more complicated [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/63267/211655) with different specifications.

Comment: Do you sample "from" the vector of length n or is this vector the result of your sampling? What is your goal? Outlier detection?

Comment: my objective is outlier detection. Each sample is a vector with length equals to $n$

Comment: Do you want to find outliers in each single vector (an outlier would be an element of the vector) or do you consider a set of vectors and an outlier would be a complete vector (an odd vector amongst all the other vectors).

Comment: The outlier would be a complete vector.

Comment: It is difficult to see how vectors of a fixed length (norm) could possibly have a Normal distribution or how a $\chi^2$ distribution would be relevant to them.  Could you explain?  Perhaps instead of "length" you mean "dimension"?

Comment: @whuber, you are right; I have corrected the question

Comment: I believe you can find many answers by searching our site for [multivariate outlier detection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multivariate+outlier+is%3Aquestion+score%3A2+answers%3A1).